# How can I prevent the disappearance of loading indicator when I touch on the screen using navigator.notification.activityStart

Tags: java, cordova, phonegap-plugins

`navigator.notification.activityStart` method is getting disappear when touch on screen. Can I have any different methods for that or plugins to start and end process?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you fork the plugin and use your fork instead.

You will need to change [this line](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/src/android/Notification.java#L404) to be `notification.spinnerDialog.setCancelable(false);`

You can also create an issue on http://issues.cordova.io/ proposing the change as feature request or improvements, so it might be changed in the future

Answer (score 0):

i used another  window.plugins.spinnerDialog.show("sometext", true, {  overlayOpacity: 0.35, textColorRed: 0.1, textColorGreen: 0.1, textColorBlue: 1}); these is solving my touch event problem .